# How leave Jenkins running remotely on the server?

Tags: java, deployment, jenkins

I am running as follows Jenkins on my server:

```
$> labes@labes-jenkins:~/jenkins$ java -jar jenkins-1.622.war
```

But when I unplug my machine the application of jenkins goes down, as I do to get the application running at the same end my SSH session?

Note: Jenkins has the jetty embedded server inside the .war artifact.

Comment: The Jenkins has the jetty server built into the artifact .war, my network temporarily crashed and lost the connection with the served through SSH, still tried to access the URL normally without being remotely connected to the server and do not quite understand why application is running.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative 1
Run the war-file in a Tomcat installation. It is probably installable in your dist as a service. Then you can probably access it through port :8080.

Alternative 2
Use the "screen" command. http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: Thank​ you so much​ Alexander Kolodziej! The Jenkins is distributed as a war and therefore can be deployed in an application server such as Tomcat or Jetty. Call Tomcat home of the <tomcat>. You should also have ant installed on your computer it will use it to compile the code and run the tests. Download the latest version of Jenkins and put in the <tomcat>/webpps/. Start the application server by running the script <tomcat>/bin/startup.sh. After that, you can access the jenkins web interface at the URL http://localhost:8080/jenkins/ in your browser.